# Android - button background color shrinks the height of the button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/learn"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop ="5dp"
android:text="Hello StackOverflow"
style="@style/home_page_buttons"    
/>
```

and I am trying to give it this style

```
<style name="home_page_buttons">  
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dp</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_best_blue</item> 
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>   
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>  
     <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

This line:

```
 <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
```

makes the backgrond white as I wanted, but for some reason, it shrinks down the height of the button and makes it ugly.

Any idea why that happens and how to stop this side effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABDOU is right, this could be a solution for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#BBBBBB" 
            android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#555555" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>    
</shape>
```

Create this as `XML` in `drawable`, and set this to your `BackgoundColor`

Comment: you mean put this xml in the directory where ordinarily I would have the images?

Comment: yes, i put mine into drawable then backgoundColor="@drawable/yourfile" for the button background

Answer (score 3):

The default button has a fixed minimum height, which is equal to the height of the underlying image. Here, since you are using a color, it has no minimum height. So, it takes up the height of the text. For your case, you will have to fix the height of your buttons.

A better way is to use custom button images.

Comment: got it, but I don't really have a way to make quick images. Is there another way that does not deal with the images?

Comment: You could use Shape drawables. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 1):

when you make `style="@style/home_page_buttons"` you change the default style of the android button

if you want keep it, just make a background image for your button

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is version dependent or due to any recent changes Since I have a very recent version of Android Studio, but I seem to have at least some degree of success restoring the extra space by specifying the Padding attribute.

Simply by adding this attribute:

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

The Button will regain most of that space it lost. I Recommend tuning the number, or possibly splitting the Attribute up into its 4 Directional Variants to customize the spacing to however much you want.

This seems to also apply for EditText as well as Buttons, as both appear to have the same problem.